# Issue in presenting view controller after pushing another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have three view controllers -> A, B, C; A being the initial view controller.

Due to some requirement, i am pushing B view contoller over A view contoller.

After some processing, I am also presenting C view contoller over A view controller.

But if i am going to B in the time the processing happens, C view controller is presenting on B view controller.

Instead, i want when i go back from B, then C should be visible over A view controller.

I am doing the presentation and pushing programatically.

I tried to present C view controller over A ->

```
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: C)
navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
A.present(C, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

i want C to present on A only, instead it is getting presented over B.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pop() your B controller, and only then present() your C controller

Comment: But i don't want it to be like that. Actually, when A opens, within few seconds if C is supposed to be presented, but in between if someone taps and opens some other B screen. Then, C should not be presented on B. If i present C after popping B, then we can see the transition of B opening later. I don' t want that. And also i don't want to allow interaction on A when B pops before C gets presented.